Using WiFi and Ethernet for same LAN at the same time, resolver issue
MacBook Pro M3 max, macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
Connected to a LAN with Wifi using DHCP. I have also a dock with 10G ethernet card connected to 10G switch on the same LAN using DHCP. There are also some other computers connected with 10G to the same switch.
Ethernet adapter is before WiFi in network service order in System Preferences. Everything works fine when I connecting to other computers from it.
Problem:
When MBP m3 is connected to WiFi and to ethernet at the same time, it registers its name with DHCP on the router for both addresses.
% host mbp-m3
mbp-m3 has address 192.168.1.196
mbp-m3 has address 192.168.1.113

.196 is wifi address and .113 is the ethernet. When I am connecting from other computers to this mbp-m3 (say, with ssh or any other app), their resolver choose either one address or another in a non-predictable way. So sometimes it chooses slower WiFi address instead of 10G. But I'd like it always choose ethernet address when MPB is connected to ethernet. And choose WiFi address otherwise.
What would be the best way to do this?
[UPDATE]
The easiest and simplest thing to do is just turn off WiFi just as @SteveChambers suggested. Unfortunately, it will also disable airdrop, unlocking with watch, etc.
The best solution may be to temporarily change DHCP hostname on wifi interface. Or change mDNS hostname on wifi interface. I could use mbp-m3.local also. But I don't see a way to do this.

How are you connecting these other computers to this Macintosh? File sharing? SSH?

Honestly, the easiest and simplest thing to do is just turn off WiFi. Macs don't combine multiple network interfaces to make a faster connection, and sometimes they choose the one you would rather they did not for reasons that are not apparent.

@IconDaemon let's say ssh.

Where are you getting the output "mbp-m3 has address 192.168.1.196"?

@SteveChambers disabling wifi is possible but not optimal solution, unfortunately. As it will also disable airdrop, unlocking with watch, etc. The best solution may be to temporarily change DHCP hostname on wifi interface. Or change mDNS hostname on wifi interface. I could use mbp-m3.local also. But I don't see a way to do this.

@Allan cmd-line command: 'host mbp-m3'

Did you manually configure that?

@Allan I did not. This is what router's DNS returns naturally when a single computer is registered to the same LAN with multiple ip addresses and same DHCP hostname names.

let's make sure it's your router sending that data.  Try nslookup mbp-m3. what do you get?

@Allan ╰─ nslookup mbp-m3                                                                               ─╯
Server:  2a00:<...>
Address: 2a00:<...>#53
Name: mbp-m3
Address: 192.168.1.113
Name: mbp-m3
Address: 192.168.1.196

Ahhhh... You've got two entries for the same name and it will connect to the one that replies first, not the fastest.

Why can’t your router issue a static IP and override DNS name on the MAC address for the WiFi connection? Or set up a second network subnet for WiFi so each pulls a different network so you can steer the routing table on the other computers to the preferred network?  This really isn’t a Mac problem - any OS with two active connections would have the same problem.

@bmike well, on linux I would setup two DHCP client configs, one for wifi-only (hostname mbp-m3 for any interface) and second for eth+wifi (eth hostname: mbp-m3, wifi hostname mbp-m3-wifi). Then on ethernet connects and disconnects I will exchange configuration and force DHCP client to renew lease with a new hostname over wifi interface. That way mbp-m3 will be resolved to the ip address of eth interface if it is connected, otherwise it will be resolved to wifi ip address. Does it make sense? But I do now see a way how to implement it in macOS.

@Allan It usually (but not always) resolved in round-robin. First "ping mbp-m3" resolves to .196, second same "ping" to .113 and so on. Well, it is not the resolver issue, but it is my problem WITH the resolver. I know how one could fix it in Linux. But unfortunately I do not sufficient experience of configuring DHCP or mDNS in macOS.

On macOS @NikkiChumakov I use DHCP Client ID on wifi to tell the router which interface gets which DNS name, but I suppose that depends on your router settings. I'd try that first and then see if you can manage things on the network side. You can specific a MAC address per interface as well - depends on which router method you prefer or have ready to go. This is basically the same suggestion as Allan has made.


Using WiFi and Ethernet for same LAN at the same time, resolver issue

It's not a resolver issue.  You are running into one of the pitfalls of having a dual/multihomed computer host connected to the same network.  You have two different paths (routes) to the same network - it has to create routes, host names, etc. so you'll get and stay connected.
To visualize this, don't think of your Mac has having an IP or a hostname, but the network adapter is what gets the address and name (for resolution).

When MBP m3 is connected to WiFi and to ethernet at the same time, it registers its name with DHCP on the router for both addresses.
mbp-m3 has address 192.168.1.196
mbp-m3 has address 192.168.1.113


Normally a DHCP server, especially one from a consumer grade router won't assign the same hostname to a different network address(mapped to a MAC address). You can assign multiple network adapters the same name, but it will introduce a number of issues - some of which you're already experiencing.


When I am connecting from other computers to this mbp-m3 (say, with ssh or any other app), their resolver chooses either one address or another in a non-predictable way.

It is most likely that the DNS cache got populated in the order in which it "found" the host adapters and this is based on latency (response time), not on speed. So, if the adapter first on the list is WiFi, it will select that one.  Remember, naming two different adapters the same hostname will "confuse" the resolver and when it runs across the first entry, it will use that one.
Solution:  Use DHCP reservations
Your Internet Router DHCP server should have the ability to reserve IP addresses for each interface.  Get the MAC address for each one and assign them like in the example below.



Hostname
MAC Addr.
IP Address




MacBook-m3-Wifi
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE
192.168.1.121


MacBook-m3-10G
FF:GG:HH:II:JJ
192.168.1.212



Just for completeness, you can have both interfaces with the same name as long as they're on different networks.  I have a Synology NAS sitting between my home network and my lab with an Ethernet interface connecting to each one.  I can access the NAS from the lab network by going to Synology.homelab and from my homenetwork by going to Synology.home.

Setting unique STATIC hostnames for each interface at router is possible, but it would force me to manually choose which hostname to use each time I access the host. This is an error-prone approach and could be avoided if only macOS allowed a unique DHCP or mDNS hostname to be dynamically used and set. For example, on Linux this is entirely possible by configuring dhclient.conf

Why not have WiFi on and not joined to the network @NikkiChumakov AirDrop and handoff work without any network, so have you tested that?

@bmike This could be the best solution. But how to disassociate MacBook wifi from AP without turning it off?
